# Data is not inserting to Firebase firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am inserting simple data into Firebase firestore using Hashmap. The data contains the continent name, country name and country flag image. But data is not inserted into the firestore, and toast in addOnFailuresListner is showing.
This is addCountry XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddCountryActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/appbar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/include"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Add New Country"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Select Continent"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyles">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/auto_complete_continent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:text="Select Continent"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Select Country"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyles">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/auto_complete_country"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="none"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:text="Select Country" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Browse Flag Image"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFlag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@color/dark_gray"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/browseBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/app_basic_color"
                android:text="Browse"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/insertBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/app_basic_color"
                android:text="INSERT data"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This list_items XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1">
</TextView>
```

This is addCountry java file

```
package com.example.universityhubfyp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class AddCountryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] continents = {"Asia", "Africa", "Europe", "North America", "South America", "Australia/Oceania","Antarctica"};
    String[] countries = {"Afghanistan (AF)","Aland Island (AX)","Albania(AL)","Algeria (DZ)","American Samoa (AS)", "Andorra(AD)","Angola (AO)","Anguilla (Al)","Antartica(AQ)","Antigua and Barbuda (AG)","Aregentina(AG)", "Armenia (AM)","Aruba (AW)","Australia (AU)","Austria (AT)","Azerbaijan (AZ)","Bahamas (BS)", "Bahrain (BH)","Bangladesh (BD)","Barbados (BB)","Belarus (BY)","belgium (BE)","Belize (BZ)", "Benin (BJ)","Bermuda (BM)","Bhutan (BT)", "Bolivia, Pleurinational State of (BO)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina (BA)","Botswana (BW)","Brazil (BR)","British Indian Ocean Territory (IO)", "British Virgin Islands (VG)","Brunei Darussalam (BN)","Bulgaria ( BG)","Burkina Faso (BF)", "Burundi (BI)","Cambodia (KH)","Cameroon (CM)","Canada (CA)","Cape Verde (CV)","Cayman Islands (KY)", "Central African Republic (CF)","Chad (TD)","Chile (CL)","China (CN)","Christmas Island (CX)", "Cocos(kelling) Islands (CC)","Colombia (CO)","Comoros (KM)","Congo (CG)", "Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The (CD)","Cook Islands (CK)","Costa Rica (CR)","Cote divoire (CL)", "Croatia (HR)","Cuba (CU)","Curacao(CW)","Cyprus (CY)","Czech Republic (CZ)","Denmark (DK)", "Dijibouti (DJ)","Dominica (DM)","Dominican Republic (DO)","Ecuador (EC)","Egypt (EG)", "El Salvador (SV)","Equatorial Guiena(GQ)","Eritrea (ER)","Estonia (EE)","Ethioia (ET)", "Falkland Islands (malvinas) (FK)","Faroe Islands (FO)","Fiji (FJ)","Finland (FL)","France (FR)",
            "French Guyana (GF)","French Polynesia (PF)","Gabon (GA)","Gambia (GM)","Georgia (GE)","Germany (DE)", "Ghana (GH)","Gibralter (Gl)","Greece (GR)","Greenland (GL)","Grenada (GD)","Guadeloupe (GP)","Guam (GU)", "Guatemala (GT)","Guemsey (GG)","Guinea (GN)","Guinea-bissau (GW)","Guyana (GY)","Haiti (HT)", "Holy See (Vatican City State) (VA)","Honduras (HN)","Hong Kong (HK)","Hungary (HU)","Iceland (IS)", "India (IN)","Indonesia (ID)","Iran, Islamic Republic Of (IR)","Iraq (IQ)","Ireland (IE)", "Isle Of Man (IM)","Israel (IL)","Italy (IT)","Jamaica (JM)","Japan (JP)","Jersey (JE)","Jordan (JO)", "Kazakhstan (KZ)","Kenya (KE)","Kiribati (Kl)","Kosovo (XK)","Kuwait (KW)","Kyrgyzstan (KG)", "Lao People's Democratic Republic (LA)","Latvia (LV)","Lebanon (LB)","Lesotho (LS)","Liberia (LR)", "Libya (LY)","Liechtenstein (LI)","Lithuania (LT)","Luxembourg (LU)","Macau (MO)", "Macedonia (FYROM) (MK)","Madagascar (MG)","Malawi (MW)","Malaysia (MY)","Maldives (MV)","Mali (ML)", "Malta (ML)","Marshall Islands (MH)","Martinique (MQ)","Mauritania (MR)","Mauritius (MU)","Mayotte (YT)", "Maxico (MX)","Micronesia, Federated States Of  (FM)","Moldova, Republic Of (MD)","Monaco (MC)", "Mangolia (MN)","Montenegro (ME)","Montserrat (MS)","Morocco (MA)","Mozambique (MZ)","Myanmar (MM)", "Namibia (NA)","Nauru (NR)","Nepal (Np)","Netherlands (NL)","New Caledonia (NC)","New Zealand (NZ)", "Nicaragua (NI)","Niger (NE)","Nigeria (NG)","Niue (NU)","Norfolk islands (NF)","North Korea (KP)", "Northern Mariana islands (MP)","Norway (NO)","Oman (OM)","Pakistan (PK)","Palau (PW)","Palestine (PS)", "Panama (PA)","Papua New Guinea (PG)","Paraguay (PY)","Peru (PE)","Philipines (PH)", "Pitcaim Islands (PN)","Poland (PL)","Portugal (PT)","Puerto Rico (PR)","Qatar (QA)","Reunion (RE)",
            "Romania (RO)","Russian Federation (RU)","Rawanda (RW)","Saint Barthelelemy (BL)", "Saint Helena,Ascension And Tristan Da Cunha(SH)","Saint Kitts and Nevis (KN)","Saint Lucia (LC)", "Saint Martin (MF)","Saint Pierre And Miquelon (PM)","Saint Vincent & The Grenadines (VC)","Samoa (WS)", "San Marino (SM)","Sao Tome And Principe (ST)","Saudi Arabia (SA)","Senegal (SN)","Serbia (RS)", "Seychelles (SC)","Sierra Leone (SL)","Singapore (SG)","Sint Marten (SX)","Slovakia (SK)","Slovenia (SL)", "Solomon Islands (SB)","Somalia (SO)","South Africa (ZA)","South Korea (KR)","South Sudan (SS)", "Spain (ES)","Sri Lanka (LK)","Sudan (SD)","Suriname (SR)","Swaziland (SZ)","Sweden (SE)", "Switzerland (CH)","Syrian Arab Republic (SY)","Taiwan (TW)","Tajikistan (TJ)", "Tanzania, United Republic Of (TZ)","Thailand (TH)","Timor-leste (TL)","Togo (TG)"," Tokelau(TK)", "Tonga (TO)","Trinidad & Tabago (TT)","Tunisisa (TN)","Turkey (TR)","Turkmenistan (TM)", "Turks and Caicos Islands (TC)","Tuvalu (TV)","Uganda (UG)","Ukraine (UA)", "United Arab Emirates (UAE) (AE)","United Kingdom (GB)","United States (US)","Urguay (UY)", "US Virgin Islands (VI)","Uzbekistan (UZ)","Vanuatu (VU)","Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic Of (VE)", "Vietnam (VN)","Wallis And Futuna (WF)","Yemen (YE)","Zambia (ZM)","Zimbabwe (ZW)"};
    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteContinents, autoCompleteCountries;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItems;
    String continentItem, countryItem;

    ImageView flagImage;
    Button browsBtn, insertBtn;
    Uri filepath;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_country);

//*****************************Continent and country Picker************************
        autoCompleteContinents = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_continent);
        autoCompleteCountries = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_country);
        adapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items, continents);
        autoCompleteContinents.setAdapter(adapterItems);
        autoCompleteContinents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                continentItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            }
        });

        adapterItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items, countries);
        autoCompleteCountries.setAdapter(adapterItems);
        autoCompleteCountries.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                countryItem = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            }
        });
        //**************************************END***************************************

        //**************************************Browse Image from storage***************************************
        browsBtn = findViewById(R.id.browseBtn);
        flagImage = findViewById(R.id.imgFlag);

        browsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Dexter.withContext(AddCountryActivity.this)
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityIfNeeded(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Image File"), 1);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                                permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });

        //**************************************End***************************************

        insertBtn = findViewById(R.id.insertBtn);
        insertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                insertCountryData();

            }
        });
    }
    //**************************************Browse Image from storage***************************************
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)  {
        if (requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            filepath=data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);
                bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                flagImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){

            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
//**************************************End***************************************
//**************************************Insert Country Data to fire base***************************************

    private void insertCountryData(){
        String continent = continentItem.trim();
        String country = countryItem.trim();


        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("File Uploader");
        dialog.show();



        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference("Image1"+new Random().nextInt(50));

        storageReference.putFile(filepath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                                dialog.dismiss();

                                HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("ContinentName", continent);
                                map.put("CountryName", country);
                                map.put("FlagImage", uri.toString());

                                
                                firestore.collection("Countries").document(country.toString()).set(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Toast.makeText(AddCountryActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(AddCountryActivity.this, "Not Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
//                                FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
//                                DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("CountryList");
//                                databaseReference.push().setValue(map);
                                //Toast.makeText(AddCountryActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                startActivity(new Intent(AddCountryActivity.this,AdminMainActivity.class));
//                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
                        float percent = (100 * snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        dialog.setMessage("Uploded: "+(int)percent+"%");
                    }
                });

    }

    //**************************************End***************************************

    //*************************onBackPress going back**************************************
    // onBackPressed starts.
//  onBackPressed single click going back to the previous activity.
//  onBackPressed double click app is close.
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1)
            startActivity(new Intent(AddCountryActivity.this,AdminMainActivity.class));
        finish();
//            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        if (counter ==2)
//            super.onBackPressed();
    }
    // onBackPressed ends
    //*****************************End**********************************
}
```

Comment: What is the message that you get?

Comment: It toasts "Not Done" @Alex Mamo

Comment: Have you tried to log the error message `Toast.makeText(AddCountryActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` rather than "Not Done"? Most likely you're getting [PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404), right?

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved, the issue was in the rules in the firestore. @Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

Answering as Community wiki, As mentioned by Alex Mamo in above comments.

Can you try to log the error message by
`Toast.makeText(AddCountryActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
Instead of “Not Done”.

You can refer to this [Document](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) on How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.